# i want to display searched bluetooth device using iOS programming? please give me a code snipet

Tags: ios

I want to search and display BlueTooth device programmatically , can anyone help me to display devices in iOS programming.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have just commited my LGBluetooth framework, which is very easy to use

Check it out
https://github.com/DavidSahakyan/LGBluetooth

Use this line of code to get nearby devices

```
#import "LGBluetooth.h"
#import CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h
........

    [[LGCentralManager sharedInstance] scanForPeripheralsByInterval:4
                                                         completion:^(NSArray *peripherals)
     {
         for (LGPeripheral *peripheral in peripherals) {
             NSLog(@"%@", peripheral.cbPeripheral.name);
         }
     }];
```